# How to display different Google Map view?

Tags: android, google-maps, action-menu

I am using ActionBar Menu to give option for google map display. I want to display different maps. In my code I am not able to switch for different map. Help me to solve the code mistake.

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_maps, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

//ActionBar Menu icon listerner like clicking options
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.smap:

            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Satellite view", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        case R.id.hmap:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        case R.id.tmap:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

        case R.id.nmap:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post the mapview code? To check if is well formed. BTW, any exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is perfect but You just missed `break` in every case.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.smap:

            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Satellite view", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;    

        case R.id.hmap:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            break;

        case R.id.tmap:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            break;

        case R.id.nmap:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            break;

        default:
            break;
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `break` after each `case` ;)
that's why always the last one is selected